# What are the benefits of creating a corporation in Delaware?

Tags: united-states, incorporation

More than half of public and Fortune 500 companies are incorporated in Delaware. What are the legal benefits of creating a corporation in Delaware over any other state?

Comment: https://www.bizfilings.com/toolkit/research-topics/incorporating-your-business/why-incorporate-in-delaware-or-nevada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Court Of Chancery**

The Court Of Chancery is a court decided by a bench trial (trial by just a judge), meaning no jury is involved.

Companies tend to try to stay away from jury trials for a number of reasons:

1. Juries tend to vote more sympathetically than judges
2. Juries tend to award more money for damages
3. jury trails can affect public opinion
4. juries tend to distrust corporation

> **Tax laws**

- Delaware has no sales tax (doesn't matter if the company is in Delaware, as long as it incorporated in the state of Delaware.)
- Delaware doesn't have a corporate tax
- Delaware doesn't have a personal property taw
- No value-added tax (doesn't tax business transactions)

> **Privacy policy**

Delaware doesn't require companies to disclose information of workers in the company.

Comment: And of course, because of all these things, Delaware has a very strong case law with respect to corporate law, which means that what you can and can not due has likely already been defined and spelt out by precedence.